# Iframe get xml value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml, iframe

For an application I need to retrieve a xml value from an online
[iframe](http://meb.elia.be/imbalance_new.asp?lang=E%20iframe)

In the html code under body you can find the xml with the required values to retrieve. (xml > rs:data > z:row > instantnrv).
Is it possible to retrieve this value every 2 minutes in a mobile application using html, js, jquery,...?

I have never done something similar before and can't find proper documentation or information on the internet...

So has anybody any ideas how this can be accomplished?

Comment: Is the src of the iframe within the same domain as the hosting page?  If not, you'll be stopped by the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy)

Comment: yes it is within same domain, so how can I retrieve this xml value?